# Which verb for "get off" / "leave" the Shuto Expressway?

Tags: word-choice, translation, verbs

I'm not sure which way to say something like exit/leave/depart/get off/escape is most appropriate when the thing I want to get off is the system of expressways in Tokyo called the Shuto 首都高.

I'm not sure that any of these would be right:

- 出発する
- 下車する
- 残す
- 終了するには

Comment: FYI, 出発する is more like "to set out from a place"; 下車する is strictly "to exit or disembark from a vehicle"; 残す is unrelated; and 終了する is more like "to complete an action".

Comment: Just so long as 脱線 doesn't apply it's all good, no?  hehehe...

Comment: @senshin: Yes I was pretty sure it would come down to semantics / idiomatic points.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use 降りる. User @Chocolate is also fond of 出る

> 高速を降りる
>   高速を出る

You can use these in the same way to express your idea of getting off of one form of expressway onto another.

> 首都高を降りて高速(or whatever)に入る・乗る

Just to address your original guesses:

出発する is to depart, as in the place of origin.

下車する is to get out of a car/vehicle.

残す is to leave something in the same way that you might leave food uneaten.

終了 is when something finishes.

Comment: 「高速を出る」も足して～---

Comment: What I actually want to do is get **off** the Shuto **onto** a "proper" expressway out of Tokyo, like the 中央道. But I don't want to get off it onto the normal streets.

Comment: @hippietrail ah sorry, that wasn't immediately clear to me. I'm not familiar with that regional jargon. I'm pretty sure you can still use it in the same way, though... △△を降りて◯◯に乗る? Or Or ~を出て高速に乗る？首都高から～に乗る・入る？

Comment: No problem I wasn't sure how much of my particular situation I should put in to make a question about language (-:

Comment: 「首都高を降りて高速に入る・乗る」 makes no sense as 首都高 is a 高速.

Answer (score 4):

"get off the Shuto onto a "proper" expressway out of Tokyo, like the 中央道."

In this case, I'd also say:

> 首都高を抜けて中央道に入る drive out of/through Shutokou and continue onto Chuoudou

Comment: おおおひさしぶり～おかえり～～～!!!