# 'Get on' a road

Tags: word-choice, words, meaning

In English, when giving directions, there are two possible constructions you can use when telling someone which road to use for a given segment of the trip:

- 'take', which refers to the entire journey along that road ('take I-35 to 183')
- 'get on', which only refers to the beginning point of the journey along that road - you have to then explicitly refer to the end as well with 'get off' or 'go to' or something ('get on I-35 and get off at 183')

The first one corresponds just fine to Japanese 通る, but is there a Japanese equivalent of the second? I can imagine multiple options (at the very least 乗る or 入る, depending on the metaphor being used), but I don't think I've ever actually come across a word for this.

Comment: Related discussion [here](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/15632/which-verb-for-get-off-leave-the-shuto-expressway)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Informally, we say 「～～に[乗]{の}る」 or 「～～に[入]{はい}る」.

Formally and officially, we say 「～～に[進入]{しんにゅう}する」.